# PHP preg_match adding a character

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm just trying to add an underscore to this `preg_match` parameter here's what I have :

```
/^[a-z\d]{2,64}$/i
```

How would I add an underscore to this regex ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would allow another char in the matching, you should just add it to the maching group

```
/^[_a-z\d]{2,64}$/i
```